# Choose multiple optional arguments with argparse in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line, argparse

I am using `argparse` in Python 3 to accept command-line arguments into a script.

```
import argparse

cli_argparser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='')
cli_argparser.add_argument('-n', '--number', type=int, help="Pass a number 'n' to script.", required=False)
cli_argparser.add_argument('-q', '--query', help="Pass a query to the script", required=False)
cli_argparser.add_argument('-o', '--outfile', help="Saves the output to an external file.", required=False)
cli_args = cli_argparser.parse_args()

if (cli_args.number):
    print ("\n--number has the value '" + str(cli_args.number) + "'\n")
elif (cli_args.query):
    print ("\n--query has the value '" + cli_args.query + "'\n")
elif (cli_args.outfile):
    print ("\n--output has the value '" + cli_args.outfile + "'\n")
else:
    print ("\nNo Arguments passed. Set or Use a default value...\n")
```

Is there a way to make sure that if one specific argument is selected, another one MUST be specified? For instance, if `-o` is specified, it must also contain `-n` before or after `-o`.

I tried adding an `if` condition, like so:

```
if (cli_args.number):
    print ("\n--number has the value '" + str(cli_args.number) + "'\n")
elif (cli_args.query):
    print ("\n--query has the value '" + cli_args.query + "'\n")
elif (cli_args.outfile):
    if (cli_args.number):
        print ("\n--output has the value '" + cli_args.outfile + "'\n")
    else:
        print ("\n--number not specified. Exit..")
else:
    print ("\nNo Arguments passed. Set or Use a default value...\n")
```

The result is that, if only `-o` is specified, the script exits (as expected), however, if `-n` is added, the first condition is True.

```
$ python test.py -o output.txt

--number not specified. Exit..

$ python test.py -o output.txt -n 100

--number has the value '100'
```

How would I modify this such that if only `-n` is specified, the 1st condition is true and if `-o` is specified, it requires `-n` too and then executes the 3rd condition? Would something like `cli_args.number AND cli_args.outfile` work? Or is there an in-built function in `argparse` for this?

Comment: Yes, your `and` would work, you'd need to make sure it was the first condition in your `if` chain however, alternatively take your current code and move the `outfile` block to the top

Comment: `argparse` doesn't have any `inclusive` testing.  Testing after parsing works well, especially considering that the arguments can occur in any order.  `is None` is a good test, since the default default `None` cannot occur in the command line.

Answer (score 0):

```
elif (cli_args.outfile):
    if (cli_args.number):
        print ("\n--output has the value '" + cli_args.outfile + "'\n")
```

This branch of logic is unreachable in your code as whenever `cli_args.number` is true, it would have fulfilled the first condition in your if ... else branch.

You could check for `outfile and number` first, or you could change the logic in the first if statement to if `number and not outfile`.